# Idiomatic pattern to initialize UIViews in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, initialization

In `Objective-C` I had evolved the pattern of having both an `awakeFromNib` and `initWithFrame:` method which invoked their `super`'s and then called a `_commonInit` where I put all my own code. E.g.

```
- (void)_commonInit {
    // Initialize stuff here
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self _commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self _commonInit];
}
```

So I'm trying to reuse this pattern in my UIView subclasses that I'm porting to Swift:

```
func _commonInit() {
    // initialize code here
}

override init(frame:CGRect) {
    super.init(frame:frame)
    self._commonInit()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self._commonInit()
}
```

Is this the right way to do it? I'm curious why the `init(coder...)` is `required`. Especially when all I do is call the `super` version. I seem to recall that the reason I used `awakeFromNib` in the `Objc` version was because any changes applied from nib restoration didn't happen until sometime later than `initFromCoder:`.

Answer (score 4):

Having a `commonInit` method that gets called from your initializers is a perfectly fine pattern for cases where you have more than one designated (or required) initializer. It's not the only pattern, though.

To address each of your doubts in turn (and add some related points)...

- `init(coder:)` is required because you're subclassing a class that declares conformance to the `NSCoding` protocol. That protocol demands that all instances of all subclasses be able to initialize from an archive.

  You don't actually have to do anything in `init(coder:)` unless you save state in `encodeWithCoder(_:)`, though. But because it's possible for a subclass to have encodable state that's not inherited, initialization safety requires that the subclass be responsible for this initializer (even if all it does is call super).
- You use `awakeFromNib()` in any custom class loaded from a nib/storyboard to take care of initialization that needs to happen only after an object's outlets and actions have been hooked up.

  When Cocoa (Touch) loads a nib, it first initializes each object (with `init(coder:)`), then after all the objects are "live", it connects all the `IBOutlet` variables and the targets for all of the `IBAction`s sent by controls. After all that's done, it calls `awakeFromNib()`.
- There's a caveat—a paradox, even—to using the `commonInit` pattern in Swift: You must initialize properties (aka instance variables) before calling `super.init()`, and you can't access `self` (including to call methods on `self`) until after calling `super.init()`. So you can't have a `commonInit` method that sets the initial values of properties.

  You *can* have properties whose types are implicitly unwrapped optionals. Those are automatically initialized to `nil`, and then you can set a "real" initial value in your `commonInit` method:

  ```
  var name: String!
  init(frame: CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: frame)
      self.commonInit()
  }
  init(coder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: coder)
      self.commonInit()
  }
  private func commonInit() {
      name = // something...
  }
  ```

An alternative pattern that gets around this issue is to supply initializers (or even lazy initializers) for each of your properties. If you do this, you don't need a `commonInit` method, because the property initializers will be implicitly called from whichever `init` actually gets used (or in the case of lazy initializers, when the property is first accessed).

```
class MyView: UIView {
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! MyAppDelegate
    lazy var name: String = { /* compute here */ }()
    init(frame: CGRect) { super.init(frame: frame) }
    init(coder: NSCoder) { super.init(coder: coder) }
    // ...
}
```

Finally, if you *do* provide a `commonInit` (or similar) method, you don't need to mangle the name with an initial underscore or anything—Swift has built-in access control, so any methods you don't want exposed to callers outside of a class can simply be marked `private`.